# How can we add more than 3 authors field for a single magzine? in Django models

Tags: django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I created a magzine model in django. But their are more than three authors of a magzine. I have written below code for three authors. If I write the code of two or three author for a single magzine then it is looks somewhat good. But if I make for more than three authors then it will looks very bad. Now I am confused, Is the method that I have created is wrong? And if it is wrong then how should I write it?

```
    author_name1 = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    designation1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    author_pic1 = models.ImageField(upload_to="authorpic", blank=True)
    author_detail1 = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=true)
    author_name2 = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    designation2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    author_pic2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="authorpic", blank=True)
    author_detail2 = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=true)
    author_name3 = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    designation3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    author_pic3 = models.ImageField(upload_to="authorpic", blank=True)
    author_detail3 = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=true)
```

Comment: Make an extra model `MagazineAuthor` with a `ForeignKey` to `Magazine`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an extra model `Author` with a [**`ForeignKey`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) to `Magazine`. If the same `Author` can write multiple `Magazine`s, you might want to use a [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) instead:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to_authorpic, blank=True)
    detail = model.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)

class Magazine(models.Model):
    # …
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(
        Author,
        related_name='magazines',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

You probably want to make `name` a [**`unique=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique) field to avoid creating two `Author` objects with the same name.